How to find the largest set of coprimes between two numbers M and N?
First, consider this simpler problem:
Given a number $N$, find the maximum set of co-primes $A$ (i.e. $\forall a, b \in A\implies \text{GCD}(a, b) == 1$) such that each number $a\in A$ is $a < N$.
From some experiments I ran, I found that $A$ is simply the set of primes smaller than $N$ (that is considering the sets I found are the longest). I did only test small numbers so this intuitively makes sense (though may be wrong), but is this a rule? Will it break as $N$ increases and the density of primes lessens?
Second, for this problem:
Given two numbers $M$ and $N$, find the maximum set of co-primes $A$ (i.e. $\forall a, b \in A\implies \text{GCD}(a, b) == 1$) such that each number $a\in A$ is $M \leq a < N$.
One would suspect that the answer would be the set of primes between $M$ and $N$ but this does not hold, for example if $M=6$ and $N=20$, the set of primes is:
$\{7, 11, 13, 17, 19\}$ whereas the maximum set of co-primes (I could find) is
$\{7, 8, 9, 11, 13, 17, 19\}$. Notice that the primes are a subset. Is this also a rule? I tried searching for a nice proof but with no luck? How do we find the longest set of co-primes between two numbers?

It seems you're implicitly assuming in your definitions that $a\neq b$ for the $\gcd(a,b)=1$ to make sense. Also, regarding the maximum # of elements, with the prime factors that any $a\in A$ with $a\gt 1$contains, may there be a different element in $A$ that has any of these primes as a factor?

As $\gcd(a,1)$ is always $1$ anyway, one may require $1 \notin A$. If so, then one may consider the smallest prime factor of each element of $A$ and apply the Pigeonhole Principle to conclude that if $A$ contains more elements than there are primes less than $N$, then $A$ must contain two numbers that have the same smallest prime factor (and in particular, are not coprime).

For the first problem:
Suppose there were a number $n\in A$ with two distinct prime factors $p$ and $q$. Then we could replace $n$ with $p$ and $q$ separately, to get a bigger set.
So every number in $A$ ie either a prime or a power of a prime.
The second problem is harder, and I would be surprised if it had such a simple solution.

You can also include $1$.

@RossMillikan: $1=29^0$ :-) (More seriously: you are of course right. I should have said that every number in $A$ has at most one prime factor.)

Each number in your set has to have its prime factors that are not factors of any other number in the set.  For the range $M$ to $N$ you can start with the primes.  You then want to look at the composite numbers in the range which are products of primes less than $M$.  In your case of $6$ to $20$ they are $8,9,10,15,16,18$.  They are all products of $2,3,5$ so you can start with $8$ or $16$ as these are powers of $2$ and eliminate as few primes as possible.  Then you can add in $9$ or $15$.  Either one uses up $3$ and as there is no power of $5$ in range we only get one more number.

Would you agree that this doesn't lead to a general solution?

That is correct.  It may get very hard over some ranges where you have lots of choices of numbers with two or three small prime factors.  I think most of the time it will be easy, but there will be some searching to do.
